# Dynamically allocating memory for a variable inside a struct as int,double etc

Tags: c, linux, struct

I Have a struct as

```
struct myStruct {
int message;
void*packet;
};
```

is it ok to dynamically allocate memory from a function in runtime like this

```
struct myStruct* create(int type, int length)
{
if(type==1)
myStruct->packet = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
if(type==2)
myStruct->packet = (double *)malloc(length * sizeof(double));

}
```

so that my packet can be configured as double as well as int?

Comment: It would be better to use a `union` that contains the two pointer types.  The resulting code would be clearer, and would use the same amount of memory.

Comment: You also need some way of knowing if `packet` points to an `int` array or a `double` array.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your snippet when you allocate memory for the message container `myStruct`. Assuming that it is also being dynamically allocated, you can create memory for it and your array simultaneously.

The receiver of this message will need to know how to interpret the information, so we need to encode the information about type and length into it as well. Here is one way to achieve that:

```
struct myStruct {
    int message;
    int type;
    int length;
};
```

So this contains the `message` of your original structure, as well as the information passed into the `create()` function. Notice that this is just the header, without any of the data allocated yet. We can create specializations with flexible arrays to represent that data.

```
struct myStructInt {
    struct myStruct hdr;
    int data[];
};

struct myStructDouble {
    struct myStruct hdr;
    double data[];
};
```

Each distinct supported array can have its own specialization. Now, your `create()` function can do a single allocation for the entire message.

```
struct myStruct * create (int type, int length) {
    struct myStruct hdr = { 0, type, length };
    struct myStruct *m;
    size_t total = 0;
    switch (type) {
    case 1: total = sizeof(struct myStructInt) + length * sizeof(int);
            break;
    case 2: total = sizeof(struct myStructDouble) + length * sizeof(double);
            break;
    /* ... */
    }
    if ((m = malloc(total)) != NULL) *m = hdr;
    return m;
}
```

The caller would know what type of message it wanted to create, so it can properly cast the pointer to the intended type after it receives the pointer from `create()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there's an error: the struct is not allocated and the `create` function doesn't return the allocated structure. You cannot do this: `myStruct->packet = (int *)malloc(length * sizeof(int));` without before allocating `myStruct`.

I have written two samples where is used an `enum` to enumerate the type of `packet` array in the structure and a `union packet` to manage the
different kind of data.

The structure `myStruct` will contain info about the type of contents of the `packet` union and its array dimension.

The function `create`, in the 1st sample, uses only one `malloc` to allocate both structure space and packet space. In this way is more simple to deallocate the structure. Furthermore `create` may return an error on the parameter `err` to indicate error conditions, on the other hands in case of error, in this version of 1st sample, the return value of the function shall be `NULL`.

If you don't need to allocate the structure I've written a second sample that allocates only the space for the union `packet` (the 2nd sample above). Here the function `create` allocates `packet` for an already allocated structure and returns 0 or an error value if an error occurs.

Here the 1st sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum myType {
    myTypeDouble,
    myTypeInt
} myType;

typedef struct myStruct {
    myType myType;
    size_t length;
    // int message; in this sample this has no mean!
    union  {
        int * i;
        double * d;
    } packet;
} myStruct;

myStruct * create(myType mtype, size_t length, int *err)
{
    myStruct * ms = NULL;
    int retVal=0;

    size_t mlen = sizeof (myStruct);

    switch(mtype) {
    case myTypeInt:
        mlen += sizeof(int)*length;
        break;

    case myTypeDouble:
        mlen += sizeof(double)*length;
        break;
    default:
        mlen=0;
        retVal=1;
        break;
    }
    if (mlen) {
        ms = malloc(mlen);  // One malloc allocates struct and packet.
        if (ms != NULL) {
            ms->length = length;
            ms->myType=mtype;
            /* Don't care myType, the usable space is after
               the structure dimension then ms->packet.i=[...]
               should be also ms->packet.d=(double *)(ms+1);
            */
            ms->packet.i=(int *)(ms+1);
        } else {
            retVal=2;
        }
    }
    if (err)
        *err=retVal;

    return ms;
}

int main(void) {
#define PACKLEN 20
    myStruct * ms[2]={NULL,NULL};
    int err=0;
    int i;

    ms[0]=create(myTypeInt,PACKLEN,&err);
    if (err)
        return 1;

    ms[1]=create(myTypeDouble,PACKLEN,&err);
    if (err) {
        if (ms[0])
            free(ms[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        ms[0]->packet.i[i] = i*2+1;
        ms[1]->packet.d[i] = 2.1*(double)(i+1);
    }

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        printf("%d ",ms[0]->packet.i[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        printf("%g ",ms[1]->packet.d[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    if (ms[0])
        free(ms[0]);

    if (ms[1])
        free(ms[1]);
}
```

Here the 2nd sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum myType {
    myTypeDouble,
    myTypeInt
} myType;

typedef struct myStruct {
    myType myType;
    size_t length;
    // int message; don't care in this sample.
    union  {
        int * i;
        double * d;
    } packet;
} myStruct;

int create(myStruct * ms, myType mtype, size_t length)
{
    int retVal=0;

    size_t mlen = 0;
    
    if (!ms) {
       return 1;
    }

    switch(mtype) {
    case myTypeInt:
        mlen = sizeof(int)*length;
        break;

    case myTypeDouble:
        mlen = sizeof(double)*length;
        break;
    default:
        mlen=0;
        retVal=2;
        break;
    }

    if (mlen) {
        /* Don't care myType! ms->packet.i=[...]
           should be also ms->packet.d=malloc(mlen);
        */
        ms->packet.i=malloc(mlen);
        if (ms) {
            ms->length = length;
            ms->myType=mtype;
        } else {
            retVal=3;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

int main(void) {
#define PACKLEN 20
    myStruct ms[2];
    int err=0;
    int i;

    ms[0].packet.i=NULL;
    ms[1].packet.d=NULL; // Although the use of .i has the same behaviour

    err=create(&ms[0],myTypeInt,PACKLEN);
    if (err)
        return 1;

    err=create(&ms[1],myTypeDouble,PACKLEN);
    if (err) {
        if (ms[0].packet.i)
            free(ms[0].packet.i);
        return 2;
    }

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        ms[0].packet.i[i] = i*2+1;
        ms[1].packet.d[i] = 2.1*(double)(i+1);
    }

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        printf("%d ",ms[0].packet.i[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    for (i=0;i<PACKLEN;i++) {
        printf("%g ",ms[1].packet.d[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    if (ms[0].packet.i)
        free(ms[0].packet.i);

    // Although the use of packet.i has the same behaviour.
    if (ms[1].packet.d)
        free(ms[1].packet.d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can solve this problem by using a `union`.

```
typedef enum {INT_ARR, DOUBLE_ARR} myType;
struct myStruct {
    myType type;
    union {
        int *iArr;
        double *dArr;
    } value;
}
```

The advantage of using a union is that the iArr pointer and dArr pointer occupy the same memory. Which field you should access the pointer as is determined by the `type` field.

The `create` function you've supplied is seemingly incomplete, as it never allocates memory for the struct or returns anything. If you choose to use the union scheme, you could write it like this:

```
struct myStruct *create(myType type, int length) {

    // Allocate struct
    struct myStruct *res = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    res->type = type;

    if(type == INT_ARR)
        res->iArr = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    else if(type == DOUBLE_ARR)
        res->dArr = malloc(length * sizeof(double));

    return res;
    
}
```

Note that you should `free()` the result returned by this `create` function once you are done with the struct.